# How can I create custom break points in a matplotlib colorbar?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, colors

I'm borrowing an example from the matplotlib custom cmap examples page:

https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html

This produces the same image with different numbers of shading contours, as specified in the number of bins: `n_bins`:

https://matplotlib.org/_images/custom_cmap_00.png

However, I'm interested not only in the number of bins, but the specific break points between the color values. For example, when `nbins=6` in the top right subplot, how can I specify the ranges of the bins to such that the shading is filled in these custom areas:

```
n_bins_ranges = ([-10,-5],[-5,-2],[-2,-0.5],[-0.5,2.5],[2.5,7.5],[7.5,10])
```

Is it also possible to specify the inclusivity of the break points? For example, I'd like to specify in the range between -2 and 0.5 whether it's `-2 < x <= -0.5` or `-2 <= x < -0.5`.

EDIT WITH ANSWER BELOW:

Using the accepted answer below, here is code that plots each step including finally adding custom colorbar ticks at the midpoint. Note I can't post an image since I'm a new user.

Set up data and 6 color bins:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# Make some illustrative fake data:
x = np.arange(0, np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.cos(X) * np.sin(Y) * 10

# Create colormap with 6 discrete bins
colors = [(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)]  # R -> G -> B
n_bin = 6
cmap_name = 'my_list'
cm = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
        cmap_name, colors, N=n_bin)
```

Plot different options:

```
# Set up 4 subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(6, 9))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.02, bottom=0.06, right=0.95, top=0.94, wspace=0.05)

# Plot 6 bin figure
im = axs[0,0].imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=cm)
axs[0,0].set_title("Original 6 Bin")
fig.colorbar(im, ax=axs[0,0])

# Change the break points
n_bins_ranges = [-10,-5,-2,-0.5,2.5,7.5,10]
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(n_bins_ranges, len(n_bins_ranges))
im = axs[0,1].imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=cm, norm=norm)
axs[0,1].set_title("Custom Break Points")
fig.colorbar(im, ax=axs[0,1])

# Arrange color labels by data interval (not colors)
im = axs[1,0].imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=cm, norm=norm)
axs[1,0].set_title("Linear Color Distribution")
fig.colorbar(im, ax=axs[1,0], spacing="proportional")

# Provide custom labels at color midpoints
# And change inclusive equality by adding arbitrary small value
n_bins_ranges_arr = np.asarray(n_bins_ranges)+1e-9
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(n_bins_ranges, len(n_bins_ranges))
n_bins_ranges_midpoints = (n_bins_ranges_arr[1:] + n_bins_ranges_arr[:-1])/2.0
im = axs[1,1].imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=cm ,norm=norm)
axs[1,1].set_title("Midpoint Labels\n Switched Equal Sign")
cbar=fig.colorbar(im, ax=axs[1,1], spacing="proportional",
        ticks=n_bins_ranges_midpoints.tolist())
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['Red', 'Brown', 'Green 1','Green 2','Gray Blue','Blue'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: You are not actually meant to answer your question within the question (as it wouldn't be a question anymore if you already answer it, right?) Instead you can provide an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use  a `BoundaryNorm` as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.cos(X) * np.sin(Y) * 10

colors = [(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)]  # R -> G -> B
n_bin = 6  # Discretizes the interpolation into bins
n_bins_ranges = [-10,-5,-2,-0.5,2.5,7.5,10]
cmap_name = 'my_list'
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Create the colormap
cm = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
            cmap_name, colors, N=n_bin)
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(n_bins_ranges, len(n_bins_ranges))
# Fewer bins will result in "coarser" colomap interpolation
im = ax.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=cm, norm=norm)
ax.set_title("N bins: %s" % n_bin)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Or, if you want proportional spacing, i.e. the distance between colors according to their values,

```
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, spacing="proportional")
```

[image]
[image]

As the [boundary norm documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm) states

> If `b[i] <= v < b[i+1]`
>   then v is mapped to color j; as i varies from 0 to len(boundaries)-2, j goes from 0 to ncolors-1.

So the colors are always chosen as `-2 <= x < -0.5`, in order to obtain the equal sign on the other side you would need to supply 
something like `n_bins_ranges = np.array([-10,-5,-2,-0.5,2.5,7.5,10])-1e-9`

Comment: Great! Thank you for passing along the documentation link and suggesting adding (not subtracting, correct?) an arbitrary small number to shift the side of the equality. In order to continue to the make the colorbar numbers linearly spaced, would I pass the norm argument `fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, norm=norm)` as discussed in the colorbar api? https://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase

Comment: I updated the answer with what I think you mean by linear spacing.